# RethinkDB error when connect to live server on AWS

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-web-services, express, rethinkdb

Connecting to local server is working fine. But i have to maintain one centralized DB for my team. I setup rethinkdb on aws server and have to access this from local from each system in my local project

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    r.connect({
        host: '55.52.57.59',
        port: 28015,
        db: 'league'
    },function(err,conn){
        if (err) throw err;
        req['app_conn']=conn;
        next();
    });
});
```

what could i do? Please help me!

Comment: Have you opened `28015` port on this server?

Comment: on server 55.52.57.59:8080 is working fine as in my localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether you have opened 28015 port on AWS Server or not?